# Can I masquerade as another user when creating/updating Rally artifact using Rally WSAPI?

Tags: rally, wsapi

I own an application that serves a need to sync between the internal bug tracker application of company I work for and Rally. The end users usually want to have their defects in the bug tracker (B) show up in Rally (R), so we do B2R syncing using Rally WSAPI. We also have R2B sync in some cases.

When I make calls to Rally WSAPI, I use a special user account that was created especially for use by the sync application. As a result of this, the Rally artifact revisions relating to changes made using the B2R sync shows the changes as being made by this special account, rather than by the original user that created the bug or modified it.

Is there a way in which I can masquerade as another user when making the WSAPI calls?

Thanks,
Yaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change made by your application will be attributed to the user whose credentials are used to authenticate Rally WSAPI calls in your application. The author of the revision is then set by the system automatically and cannot be overwritten to attribute it to a different user.